# Using the Chrome webdriver sites thinks I am mobile

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have something strange happening with a testcase.

When I test in the IDE all works fine, yet when use the WebDriver runs elements are not found on the page.  I set up screenshots through the WebDriver and the screenshots look like the mobile view (this doesn't have the same elements as teh desktop view).  I would think that the Selenium Chrome pages should be rendered as the desktop Chrome view

I use the following to set the driver

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

As a test I have this in my testcase

```
driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
```

This returns

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36

Which looks correct, when the testcase fails to find the element, I see this

> (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.100)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.25.426924
>   (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e),platform=Linux
>   4.4.0-59-generic x86_64)

Which again looks correct

So, so my question is, is there something else that I should do to force the site to use the desktop view.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your browser window is opening at an appropriate size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that your driver window is too small, and so the website is loading the mobile view based on this, you can try:

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

or

```
# replacing the dimensions below with whatever you require
driver.set_window_size(1000, 600)
```

Comment: I had self.driver.maximize_window() in there but looks like I needed to explicitly state the window size.  Workd now.